# ASP.NET MVC 4 SAAS multi-tenancy starter kit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for SAAS multi-tenancy starter kit
with REST API enabled, windows identity foundation, JS, CSS, views, lang, customized.

Could you please share a links or approaches to do this with lates asp.net mvc **4** stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think there is a starter kit that exactly fits this definition?

Comment: From the place where I stand it should be. Multi-tenancy is trend now.

Answer (score 2):

Check ASP.NET Iteration Zero: http://aspnetzero.com/

It's a professional starter kit based on a strong framework and UI. It includes role and membership management, MULTI TENANCY and much more.

Comment: It's cool - but paid - and no sources available to look at it.

Comment: This article (http://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step) can give you an idea about code base. Also, check http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents to see idea behind this project.